# Creating own SSL on AWS and domain name

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I would like to create an SSL with AWS.

I am using Elastic Beanstalk in the following way:

```
https (ssl cert) -> www.mydomain.com -> http -> my-beanstak.eu-central-1.elasticbeanstalk.com
```

However, now I would like to add another layer of security, and do the following:

```
https (ssl cert) -> www.mydomain.com -> https (ssl cert amazon) -> my-beanstak.eu-central-1.elasticbeanstalk.com
```

So know based on article found [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-aws-certificate-manager-deploy-ssltls-based-apps-on-aws/) I am on in the point where I am creating SSL via Amazon.

My question is:

What should I put into domain name in the certificate manager? Should it be

1. my-beanstak.eu-central-1.elasticbeanstalk.com

or

2. www.mydomain.com (if so, why?)

or

3. something else..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

None of the above.

Amazon Certificate Manager only provides you with a certificate for the outside (your domain, on the ELB external interface), not the inside (between the ELB and the instance).

For end-to-end SSL (which is what your desired scenario is called), *you* have to provide the inner-certificate yourself.  But, it can be self-signed without consequence, since the browser never sees it and the ELB already knows it and thus doesn't need to validate it with a trusted CA.

See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/configuring-https-endtoend.html